# Controlling print outs in a program with command line argument

Tags: c++, ostream

I am trying to control the print outs in my program. I wrote a small script for that which takes a command line argument and decides to print or not to print depending upon the flag `-v` passed to it. Now I have to write `out(bool)` in my actual program everywhere. Is it possible to make the decision in the start of the program and just to use `out` instead of `out(bool)`.

```
class mystreambuf : public std::streambuf
{
};
mystreambuf nostreambuf;
std::ostream nocout(&nostreambuf);
#define out(b) ((b==true)?std::cout : nocout )

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    std::cout << "Program name is: " << argv[0] << "\n";

    int counter;
    bool verbose;

    if (argc == 1)
    {
        std::cout << "No command line argument passed" << argv[0] << "\n";
    }

    if (argc >= 2)
    {
        for (counter = 0; counter < argc; counter++)
        {
            std::cout << "Argument passed are: " << argv[counter] << "\n";
            if (strcmp(argv[counter], "-v") == 0)
            {
                verbose = true;
            }
            else
            {
                verbose = false;
            }
        }
    }

    out(verbose) << "\n hello world \n";

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: This sounds like what you really need is a logging framework...

Comment: As a general rule, avoid using the constant `true` and `false` in your code, they are virtually always unnecessary, and only add verbosity, which decreases readability. Don’t write `b == true`, write just `b`. Same for your (ironically named) `verbose` assignment: this can and should be accomplished in a single line (instead of *eight*): `verbose = strcmp(argv[counter], "-v") == 0;` — Furthermore, `out` should be a function, not a macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way would be to build a minimal class containing the boolean flag and a reference to the actual stream. Then the `<<` operator would be either a no-op or a delegation to the actual stream. It could be:

```
class LogStream {
    std::ostream& out;
    bool verbose;
public:
    LogStream(std::ostream& out = std::cout): out(out) {}
    void set_verbose(bool verbose) {
    this->verbose = verbose;
    }
    template <class T>
    LogStream& operator << (const T& val) {
    if (verbose) {
        out << val;
    }
    return *this;
    }
};
```

It can then be used that way:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    LogStream out;
    ...
    out.set_verbose(verbose);
    out << "\n hello world \n";
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a singleton instance that you setup at the beginning and log through. Something like:

```
class Printer {
    public: static std::streambuf getInstance() {
        if (_instance._printing) {
           return std::cout;
        }
        return _instance._nostreambuf;
    }
    static void setPrinting(bool set) {
        _instance._printing = set;
    }
    private:
    static Printer _instance;
    mystreambuf _nostreambuf;
    bool _printing;
    // delete constructors and assignment operators.
}
```

*Note: Rapid pseudo code, not tested.*

Which you would use like:

```
Printer::setPrinting(verboseBool);
Printer::getInstance() << "Print text";
```

But what you would be making is a logger. Of which there are plenty. [Here is a nice list.](https://github.com/fffaraz/awesome-cpp#logging)

Answer (score 0):

Simply make `out` a variable being one of the two options:

```
std::ostream &out = verbose ? std::cout : nocout;
```

and continue printing with `out <<`